# Ionic2 sleep mode backgroundMode and background geolocation

Tags: background, ionic2, gps, sleep

I have installed backgroundMode, backgroundGeolocation and insomnia but I'm still banging my head.

1. Background mode seems to work ok
2. after 40 secs the phone goes to sleep and backgroundGeolocation stops working
3. everything else seems to work fine eg: network connections, BLE button clicks, just not backgroundGeolocation.

I'm getting desperate and happy to pay someone for some help.

Please gurus, help me lol

home.ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          public member:Member,
          public journey: Journey,
          public backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
          public insomnia: Insomnia,
          platform: Platform) {

platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  this.insomnia.keepAwake()
    .then(
      () => console.log('success'),
      () => console.log('error')
    );
});

this.member.onLoggedIn.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.memberLoggedIn();
  }
);
this.member.onLoggedOut.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.memberLoggedOut();
  }
); 
}
```

Comment: Is not it keeping awake?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to fix this is by turning off power saving mode on my phone :(